# A dash/dolar in a pattern passed to preg_match_all strangely make the pattern does not match

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a problem with my regular expression. I am trying to match all rows from a file that contain word "RewriteBase" with possible spaces before it. The example file is:

```
    #RewriteBase /yardley/development
    RewriteBase /yardley/
```

My patterns and their results:

```
@RewriteBase\s*(.*)@ //matches both lines - OK
@RewriteBase\s*(.*)$@ //matches first line only - why?
@^.*RewriteBase\s*(.*)@ //doesn't match any - why? It should accept all characters before "RewriteBase"
```

I'm completely stuck on it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using line start anchor `^` or line end anchor `$` therefore 2nd regex will match only 2nd line and 3rd regex will match only 1st line.

You can use multiline (m) switch to match all the lines in your 3 regex:

```
$s = <<< EOF
#RewriteBase /yardley/development
RewriteBase /yardley/
EOF;
if (preg_match_all('@RewriteBase\s*(.*)$@m', $s, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[0]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "RewriteBase /yardley/development"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "RewriteBase /yardley/"
}
```